# A matriz está imprimindo os mesmos valores para todos os índices, por que?

Tags: c

Criar um algoritmo que carregue uma matriz 12 x 4 com os valores das vendas de uma loja, em que cada linha represente um mês do ano, e cada coluna, uma semana do mês.

Para fins de simplificação considere que cada mês possui somente 4 semanas. Calcule e imprima:
- Total vendido em cada mês do ano;
- Total vendido em cada semana durante todo o ano;
- Total vendido no ano.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int matriz[12][4];
    int linha, coluna;
    int totalMes[12];
    int totalSemana[48];
    int total = 0;

    for(linha=0; linha<12; linha++){
        for(coluna=0; coluna<4; coluna++){
            scanf("%d", &matriz[linha][coluna]);
        }
    }

    for(linha=0; linha<12; linha++){
        for(coluna=0; coluna<4; coluna++){          
            totalMes[linha] += matriz[linha][coluna];

            totalSemana[coluna] += matriz[linha][coluna];

            total += totalMes[linha] + totalSemana[coluna];
        }
    }

    for(linha=0; linha<12; linha++){
        printf("Total vendido no mês %d = %d:\n", linha+1, totalMes[linha]);

        for(coluna=0; coluna<4; coluna++){
            printf("LINHA = %d e COLUNA = %d\n", linha, coluna);
            printf("Total vendido na semana %d = %d:\n", coluna+1, totalSemana[coluna]);        
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("Total vendido no ano = %d:\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

cara não vejo nenhuma atribuição as suas variáveis isso está correto?

```
        for(linha=0; linha<12; linha++){
            for(coluna=0; coluna<4; coluna++){
                scanf("%d", &matriz[linha][coluna]);
            }
        }

        for(linha=0; linha<12; linha++){
            for(coluna=0; coluna<4; coluna++){

                totalMes[linha] += matriz[linha][coluna];

                totalSemana[coluna] += matriz[linha][coluna];

                total += totalMes[linha] + totalSemana[coluna];
            }

        }
```

onde você atribuiu um valor na variável matriz[linha][coluna]?

me explica isso pq até agora a sua matriz veio nula e está vazia . então soma vazio com vazio resultado = vazio

=D